# Why doesn't the swift compiler sometimes accept the shorthand argument name?

Tags: swift, swift2

The array is : `var closestAnnotations:[MKAnnotation]`

I was wondering why the swift compiler won't accept :

```
    let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
        $0.dynamicType === StationAnnotation.self
    })
```

`Cannot convert value of type (_) -> Bool to expected argument type (MKAnnotation) -> Bool`

But accepts :

```
    let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
        (annotation : MKAnnotation) -> Bool in
        annotation.dynamicType === StationAnnotation.self
    })
```

Comment: How is `closestAnnotations` declared?

Comment: Please see my edit ! :)

Comment: Smells like a bug. I thinks it's related to the fact that `.dynamicType` is not a [normal member access](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID400), but [a special expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID402). But I cannot find any reasonable explanation about this.

Comment: I'm also getting a feeling that's related to `.dynamicType `'s specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying out different versions of your code (using Xcode 7). The fix is obvious, using

```
let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
    $0 is StationAnnotation
})
```

which is the correct way to test types, works without any problems.

I have noticed that there is simple code that makes the error go away

```
let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
    print("\($0)")
    return ($0.dynamicType === StationAnnotation.self)
})
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
    return ($0.dynamicType === StationAnnotation.self)
})
```

If you notice the error message, the compiler sees the closure as `(_) -> Bool`.

That leads me to the conclusion that the expression `$0.dynamicType` is somehow optimized out.

Most interestingly

```
let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
    return true
})
```

will trigger the same error.

**So I think there are two compiler bugs:**

1. The compiler cannot infer the argument from the type of the array and that's wrong because `(_) -> Bool` should be considered as `(Type) -> Bool` when called on `[Type]`.
2. The compiler somehow optimizes `$0.dynamicType` out and that's obviously wrong.

Comment: The problem is that `.dynamicType` is not a member. That's probably why

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Yes, using `let arg = $0` and then `arg.dynamicType ==...` solves the problem, too. It's specifically connected to `$0.dynamicType`.

Comment: I have filed a bug to apple. Let's see if they will fix this :)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I am actually more amazed by the fact that the compiler won't infer `return true` as a valid closure.

Comment: Did you see that in this case, the error is different ? : `Tuple pattern cannot match  values of non-tuple type MKAnnotation`