# CollectionType filter : Swift compilation error : Tuple pattern cannot match values of non-tuple type

Tags: swift, closures, swift2

Lets suppose we have this particular case

```
let closestStationAnnotations = closestAnnotations.filter({
    return true
})
```

Where I have :

```
 let closestAnnotations:[MKAnnotation]
```

With XCode 7b6, the compiler returns :

```
Tuple pattern cannot match  values of the non-tuple type MKAnnotation
```

What does this error actually mean ?

PS: This question is related to [another I had previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412219/why-doesnt-the-swift-compiler-sometimes-accept-the-shorthand-argument-name/32412558) for those who are curious.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `.filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I witnessed multiple cases where the error message given by Xcode had little to do with the actual problem. In your particular case the real problem is that when you're using the shorthand notation (omitting the block signature), you have to use the arguments inside the block. For instance, this compiles because the single block argument `$0` is used inside of the block:

```
let c = closestAnnotations.filter { $0 === $0 }
```

This does not compile, however, because it doesn't use the block argument:

```
let c = closestAnnotations.filter { return true }
```

If you want to explicitly not use the block argument, you have to tell the compiler by using the underscore syntax:

```
let c = closestAnnotations.filter { _ in return true }
```

This limitation is sort of stupid and confusing and does not apply when you're using the regular form with a full block signature. This compiles fine:

```
let c = closestAnnotations.filter { (e: MKAnnotation) -> Bool in
    return true
}
```